Laravel : Not able to put image into s3 bucket
I have set all the necessary parameters in environment variables. This is how I instantiate my s3 driver in filesystems.php:
's3' => [
        'driver' => 's3',
        'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
        'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
        'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
        'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
        'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
        'endpoint' => env('AWS_ENDPOINT'),
    ],

In my controller file, I am trying to put the image to this s3 bucket. Here is how I attempted to do it:
// Retrieve the base64 image string from the form
    $base64Image = $request->input('user_id_image_base64');

    if ($base64Image) {
        // Extract the image data from the base64 string
        $imageData = explode(',', $base64Image)[1];
        // dd($imageData);
        $imageData = base64_decode($imageData);

        // Generate a unique file name
        $fileName = $user->username.'_id_image_' . time() . '.png';
        

        // Upload the image to S3 directly from the image data
        $disk = Storage::disk('s3');
        // dd($disk);
        //$path = 'user_id_verification/' . $fileName;
        $disk->put($fileName, $imageData, 'public');
        try{
            if ($disk->exists($fileName)) {
                \Log::info('File exists in S3 bucket.');
            } else {
                \Log::error('File does not exist in S3 bucket.');
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            \Log::error('Error checking file existence: ' . $e->getMessage());
        }
        
        }

I used dd in several places to see if the image has been loaded successfully or not, and if driver has been properly initialized or not. Everything seems to be correct. But when I put the file into bucket, and check for its existence, it throws exception production.ERROR: Error checking file existence: Unable to check existence for: u1724762574_id_image_1724762574.png . I also checked if the upload has been successful and result was false What am I doing wrong here?

I feel like there is either caching or a race condition here.  Ultimately I'm not sure why you have to check that the file is there.  If the put didn't generate an error then the file should be there.

Are you facing this issues only when base64 or actual file too

Try verify if you bucket have correct permission, this seems to be a common error in bucket permissions.
See this video for help you setup permissions right: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ar2Qz0of84o
